# How do I do a new install?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install Linux on a disk that currently contains Windows 7. I want to remove the current Windows. I have not tried anything yet because I am new to this.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/547943/how-to-get-windows-off-a-new-machine-and-install-ubuntu/547953#547953

Answer (score 0):

This link takes you to a simple tutorial on how to install Ubuntu:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_4Kh5kE3xA

If you prefer instructions on screen, try here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

If you have any further questions, feel free to log into the IRC Chat or follow up here! We, the community, are here for you